# Storing data in List And sum it #Flutter #Firebase

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter

[Need to store the text field data and store and then sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4riP.png)I am creating multiples sub category Just like to-do on button click it creates a field where user can put his/her input.
The Input is product Price Now I wanna store this all data in similar list As it's subcategories for some product and wanna display their total sum along side all values.

Comment: Could you share a bit of code? I'm pretty sure what you're trying to accomplish is doable, so a bit of context wouldn't hurt.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4riP.png

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/N4riP.png This is something I wanna implement and need to sum print on the screen for the price I will be adding in text fields and displaying complete values added also on screen. Hope you have understood and will provide me with good solution

Comment: https://github.com/talalhabib0000/sample.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using **fold** function

```
arrayName.fold(0, (result, eachItem) => result+eachItem)
```

it will add current item to result(which is 0 initially) and return it

---

eg: given your data of **List< String > items**

here is your a function that will parse the items to int and return the sum

```
int getTotal()=> items.fold(0,(total, item) {
      int? price = int.tryParse(item);
      if(price!=null) return total+price;
      else return total; 
    });
```

Although according to your existing code you have on bug, which is the price is not being updated form the text field

Therefore you must add onChanged to your text field

```
onChanged:(value) => items[index]=value,
```

Then you can display it like this

```
Text("Total price: ${getTotal()}"),
```

[image]

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/N4riP.png  This is something I wanna implement and need to sum print on the screen for the price I will be adding in text fields and displaying complete values added also on screen. Hope you have understood and will provide me with good solution

Comment: https://github.com/talalhabib0000/sample.git

Comment: @TalalHabib check the updated answer

Comment: Thankyou so much it totally and learn a new concept

Comment: @TalalHabib Could you accept the answer then. Thanks!

Comment: done accepting your solution. with that can you please tell me one more thing if I use another field outside this list and do multiplication with this sum is it possible ? If you can provide solution for that too.

Comment: the question isn't clear for me, can you elaborate it abit

Comment: Like the way you help me sum the data in text filed I wanna create a new Text Field Not the list type and wanna multiply the value of this new field with the sum.